# TemplateDoesNotExist at /users/register/

Tags: python, django

Почему то при переходе на url register.html вылезает ошибка хотя аналогичный login.html открывается без проблем

```js
users/urls.py

from django.urls import path, include

from . import views

app_name = 'users'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
]
```

```css
lak/settings.py


"""
Django settings for Lak project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-ysw8te1f87=^79$!y4a-ht@#&#-5i(pqci%-1mn8)a*0#%tedb'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'menu',
    'users'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Lak.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Lak.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Moscow'


USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

```html
users/views.py

from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import login
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm


def register(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm()
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save()
            login(request, new_user)
            return redirect('menu')
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', context)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну, на скриншоте отчётливо видно, что никакого `users/register.html` там и правда не существует

Comment: Я не понимаю. Смысле он существует а если и вправду нет то опишите в какой директории он должен быть

Comment: Он должен быть в том пути, который вы прописали в коде. Если вы прописали `users/register.html` — то значит этот файл должен существовать. Если вы хотите, чтобы файл лежал в пути `registration/register.html` (как на скриншоте) — значит именно этот путь и нужно прописать в коде

Comment: Напишите эту информацию в ответе